# Calling WCF web services from an ASP.NET web application using impersonation and channel factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, impersonation, channelfactory

I have various bits of functionality implemented in WCF web services which are currently consumed by an Excel client via a local COM-visible library. I wish to implement some of the front-end functionality in a web client. I set up my client proxy using

```
dataChannel.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;
```

ASP.NET impersonation is turned on as is windows authentication (no anonymous). When web services and web site are hosted on the same server there are no issues and the desktop user's credentials are passed from browser to web site to WCF perfectly. However, when web site and web services are hosted on different boxes (same domain, intranet only) I get 401 authentication errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are suffering from the kerberos "[double hop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx)" problem.  By default windows does not pass the kerberos authentication token onto another server so if you have user accesses webserver A and authenticates, webserver A accesses service on webserver B.  WEbserver A does not pass the auithentication through to webserver B so you get a 401.  I think [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx) should help you enable kerberos delegation between the web site server and the web service server

Comment: This [MSDN article on impersonation & delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088(v=VS.100).aspx) in WCF might also be helpful (and a bit more up to date).

Comment: Thanks for these responses. I missed the key section in the delegation section that has    When the impersonation level is Delegation, the front-end and back-end services can be on separate machines or on the same machine. Enabling delegation-level impersonation requires that Windows domain policy be configured to permit delegation. For more information about configuring Active Directory for delegation support, see [Enabling Delegated Authentication](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=99690).